# Devider between over flow menu items in action bar

Tags: android

How to show divider between action bar overflow menu items?

I have created toolbar as action bar and set following theme to activity

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">42dip</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
</style>

<!-- Popup Menu Text Color styles -->
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:showDividers">end</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dp</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-8.0dip</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/purple</item>
</style>
```

now i have created menu like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/header_kart"
        android:icon="@drawable/header_kart"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/header_right_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/header_right_menu"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_mytask"
                android:icon="@drawable/mytask"
                android:title="My Task"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_myservice"
                android:icon="@drawable/myservice"
                android:title="My Services"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/menu_setting_icon"
                android:title="Setting"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_what_is_rk"
                android:icon="@drawable/right_menu_what_is_raghukaka"
                android:title="What is Raghukaka"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_sale_on_rk"
                android:icon="@drawable/right_menu_sale_on_raghukaka"
                android:title="Sell on Raghukaka"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_support"
                android:icon="@drawable/menu_support_icon"
                android:title="Support"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_customer_care"
                android:icon="@drawable/right_menu_customer_care"
                android:title="Customer Care"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_t_and_c"
                android:icon="@drawable/menu_t_and_c_icon"
                android:title="T&amp;C"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_faq"
                android:icon="@drawable/right_menu_faq"
                android:title="FAQs"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_privacy"
                android:icon="@drawable/menu_privacy_icon"
                android:title="Privacy Policy"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/right_menu_logout"
                android:title="Logout"
                app:showAsAction="withText"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

now  i want divider between overflow menu items ...